Seeking Open Research Problems in zk Cryptography for Military Applications
I am currently working on my thesis as a researcher specializing in zero-knowledge (zk) cryptography. My focus is on identifying and solving open research problems related to the application of zk cryptography in military systems.
I am particularly interested in areas such as:

Secure communication protocols that preserve privacy.
Privacy-preserving access control systems.
Decentralized identityverification or authentication in high-security
environments.

While there are extensive applications of zk cryptography in civilian domains, I have found limited resources that discuss its application to military-specific challenges.
Could anyone provide insights, references, or unexplored areas where zk cryptography could address unique challenges in military systems? Suggestions on relevant experts, organizations, or projects would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Well, very focused military applications may be classified, no? As someone working in the area you tell us, what is unique about military crypto?

@kodlu You're right that certain applications may be classified, but the unique aspect of military cryptography lies in its extreme security requirements. It often involves scenarios where trust in intermediaries is impossible, and systems must function securely even in hostile environments. Techniques like keyless authentication, zero-knowledge proofs, and quantum-resistant algorithms are examples of technologies that push the boundaries of cryptography to meet these challenges.
